# Jboss 6.4 server is working and 7.1 is not working

Tags: java, jboss

When I run the same code for jboss server 6.4 it working fun. But when we upgrade the jboss server to 7.1, it show the below error.

```
public final HttpClientBuilder useSystemProperties() {
        this.systemProperties = true;
        return this;
    }

public static CloseableHttpClient createDefault() {
        return HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    }

CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
```

```
(default task-2) [REQUEST: PX_SUBMIT_SERVICE    ]  EXCEPTION=[TYPE :java.lang.NoSuchFieldError MESSAGE :java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder.build(HttpClientBuilder.java:769)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients.createDefault(HttpClients.java:58)
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, JBoss 7 ship with new version Apache httpclient library, you need update your code accordingly.

Comment: I tried to upgrade my apache httpclient version into 4.5.7 but it is still not working? Can you help me to check which version should I upgrade to make it works?

Comment: you should use httpclient 4.3.x version according to [here](https://github.com/apache/httpcomponents-client/blob/4.3.x/httpclient/src/main/java/org/apache/http/impl/client/HttpClientBuilder.java). 4.4.x and 4.5.x doesn't work.